# How can I do to my PC see its network adapter?

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking, network-adapter

I have installed the Windows-7 on my computer. My PC doesn't see the wifi connections, because the Windows did not detect a properly installed network adapter. I entered the "Change adapter settings" but here doesn't see anything, the page is empty. I plug in the Internet wire to my computer but didn't see it. What can I do to have wifi connect of my computer see its network adapter?

Comment: Did you install the network adapter driver?

Comment: No, because the Windows didn't detected it. When I used Linux Ubuntu there wasn't any problem.

Comment: @blackcornail different OS's come with different drivers bundled on the install CD.

Comment: I see, but what can I do in this situation?

Comment: @blackcornail Use a different computer to download the driver from the manufacturer, put the driver on a USB stick or CD, transfer the driver to the computer that needs it and then install it. You obviously have access to a computer with internet so I recommend using that computer to download the driver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to your PC manufacturer's website, look up your PC model number and look for a network adapter driver. Alternatively, if you know your network adapter brand and model number, you can go to their website and look for a driver and install that.

Answer (score 2):

You saw it on Ubuntu because different OS's come with different drivers bundled on the install CD. Ubuntu had a driver for your network card bundled in the installer and windows did not.

To get it to work go to a different computer and download the network card driver on to portable media (Burn it to a CD, put it on a USB stick, copy it to a floppy, etc.). Then take the media back to your PC and install the network card drivers. After you install the drivers the network card will show up.